# Problemas con CSS en servidor web

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

He probado mi sitio web a través de un servidor local creado a través de Codeigniter y Bootstrap 4 y funciona a la perfección. Entonces, hago la prueba en un servidor web, donde carga las imágenes pero no los estilos CSS, o al menos eso parece. El sitio en cuestión se ve de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pensé que podría ser una cuestión de las rutas, sin embargo, examino el código fuente de mi sitio web, y me encuentro con esto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://miservidor.com/assets/img/favicon.ico"/>
<!-- Common Styles Starts -->
<link href="http://miservidor.com/fonts/poppins/poppins.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://miservidor.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://miservidor.com/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Bueno... aún pareciera ser que es un problema de las rutas, pero cuando hago Ctrl + click en el vínculo de cada archivo CSS, estos se abren sin problemas. Como ejemplo, si hago click en el link de mi archivo correspondiente a la fuente Poppins, el archivo CSS se abre y reconoce plenamente la ruta del archivo, tal como se ve en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Del mismo modo, si copio el link de cualquiera de los archivos CSS (con la ruta completa) y pego en la barra de direcciones de cualquier navegador web, el archivo se abre sin problemas, tal y cual se muestra en la imagen anterior.

Por si acaso, presento mi archivo .htaccess, el cual es el siguiente:

```
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# RewriteEngine on
# RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 # allow_override On
 # mod_rewrite is installed

 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 <IfModule mod_php5.c>
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Cuál sería el problema? Le he dado vueltas al asunto pero no logro encontrar la solución.

Comment: Revisa si en tu servidor estás usando un certificado SSL. Si es así, debes cambiar las rutas para que no sean `http://` sino `https://`. También puedes validar en el código de manera dinámica si las rutas vienen con o sin protocolo seguro `https`.

Comment: Solucionado! En Codeigniter hice la modificación del base_url y le he añadido la "s" y quedó en https://.. Gracias